# How can I scrape text content from a website using tools

Tags: html

I want to extract all the text data available in my website. I am not a programmer. Is there any tools that I can look up at?

I tried using Octaprase but it is fetching data only from one page at a time

It would be great if i get to know any free tools that will help me to extract all of the website textc

Answer (score -1):

> **[Web scraper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraper/jnhgnonknehpejjnehehllkliplmbmhn?hl=en)** is a great alternative to Outwit hub which is available for Google Chrome that can be used for data acquisition. It
>   lets you set up a sitemap (plan) on how a website should be navigated
>   and what data should to be extracted. It can scrape multiple pages
>   simultaneously and even has dynamic data extraction capabilities. The
>   plugin can also handle pages with JavaScript and Ajax, which makes it
>   all the more powerful. The tool lets you export the extracted data to
>   a CSV file. The only downside to this extension is that it doesn’t
>   have many automation features built in. Learn how to use web scraper
>   to extract data from the web.

https://www.promptcloud.com/blog/best-software-tools-acquire-data/